# Diseño de un div

Tags: css, html5, div

Quería saber cómo hacen los maquetadores para darle forma a un div como el del Sgte ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No son completamente cuadrados sino que tienen forma en diagonal, como se hace este diseño? Cómo se le da esta forma a un div ? Gracias

Me refiero a la parte inclinada de la primera imagen y a la parte ovalada de la segunda como se le da esta forma a los div, sé que hay veces que se hace con imágenes pero creo que con CSS es posible inclinar o darle una forma diferente a los divs

Comment: Yo los veo cuadrados.. no esta claro a que te referis..

Comment: seguramente sean imagenes o gradientes. En cualquier caso esta pregunta no cumple los requisitos del sitio para ser una buena pregunta, te recomiendo leer el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: Yo lo que veo son divs normales, con `height, border y filtro de opacity`

Comment: He cambiado las imágenes para q sea más claro, me refiero a los bordes inferiores de los divs de las imágenes uno es ovalado y el otro está inclinafo.. es posible con CSS hacer eso?

Comment: Una posibilidad sería sesgar el div y después sesgar el contenido en el sentido contrario. Otra posibilidad sería utilizar clip-path. Si te refieres al elemento del pie de página, este podría ser un elemento svg o podría ser de nuevo cortado con  clip-path. Para recibir más ayuda por favor añade tu código

Comment: Gracias enxanea, no tengo código aún, solo que he estado viendo algunas plantillas por la red porque soy desarrollador backend, estoy apenas  aprendiendo frontend y él diseño no se me da muy bien, tengo pensado realizar un nuevo proyecto y quiero darle el diseño de una plantilla muy linda q he visto por ahí.. igual ya creo haber encontrado la forma les dejo el enlace por si alguien algún día tiene la misma duda https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6QGOhCZLdhs

Comment: podes usar un svg como fondo y jugar con el [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: Se usa border-RADIUS.

Comment: ejemplo de clip-path: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197517/81450

Answer (score 2):

Svg como imagen de fondo pintando un blanco sobre el gradiente, alineado al borde inferior y con `background-size: contain` para que se acomode.

```css
#footer {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22 viewBox%3D%220 0 1900 230%22%3E%0A  %3Cpath fill%3D%22%23FFF%22 d%3D%22M1900 208.43c-209.35-14.29-314.55-89.93-509.35-89.93-104.5 0-313.16 81.67-455.85 78.24-162.33-3.9-351.81-78.24-458.44-78.24C322 118.5 254.11 160.43 157 179 63.19 196.94 0 211.03 0 211.03V230h1900v-21.57z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E'), linear-gradient(to left, #037FD5, #03c5d5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  min-height: 340px;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  background: #fe0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <h1>Curabitur sit amet dolor varius</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum porttitor ullamcorper. Ut consequat, ante nec vestibulum suscipit, velit sapien lobortis sem, sed molestie nulla metus ac ante. Proin libero orci, porta et eros ac, ullamcorper
      aliquam urna. Nam suscipit neque ut ex laoreet aliquam. </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

El svg sin urlencodear:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1900 230">
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M1900 208.43c-209.35-14.29-314.55-89.93-509.35-89.93-104.5 0-313.16 81.67-455.85 78.24-162.33-3.9-351.81-78.24-458.44-78.24C322 118.5 254.11 160.43 157 179 63.19 196.94 0 211.03 0 211.03V230h1900v-21.57z"/>
</svg>
```

---

Otra opción con svg inline: el gradiente está aplicado en el svg, [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) hace que se estire o se centre o cropee.

La ventaja es que el svg está en el DOM y lo podes modificar con javascript o más css.

```css
body {
  background: #fe0;
}

#footer {
  min-height: 340px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
}

#footer>svg {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" viewBox="0 0 1900 230">
  <linearGradient id="grad" x2="1889.01" y1="105.51" y2="105.51" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#037fd5"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#71c8f1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#grad)" d="M1900 208.43c-209.35-14.29-314.55-89.93-509.35-89.93-104.5 0-313.16 81.67-455.85 78.24-162.33-3.9-351.81-78.24-458.44-78.24C322 118.5 254.11 160.43 157 179 63.19 196.94 0 211.03 0 211.03V0h1900v208.43z"/>
</svg>

    <h1>Curabitur sit amet dolor varius</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum porttitor ullamcorper. Ut consequat, ante nec vestibulum suscipit, velit sapien lobortis sem, sed molestie nulla metus ac ante. Proin libero orci, porta et eros ac, ullamcorper
      aliquam urna. Nam suscipit neque ut ex laoreet aliquam. </p>
  </div>
</body>
```