# ¿Como hacer un Notch en html?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer el notch que tiene este menu en html, pero no me queda dotalmente redondo usando `clip-path`, es posible que quedase perfectamente redondo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he conseguido es [algo asi](https://codepen.io/Macorreag/pen/eYJVvbY)

```css
#fondo{
    background-color:red;
}
.div-notch{
    height:30px;
    background-color:blue;

    left: calc( 50vw - 15px );
    /*For generate Clip-path use https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/*/
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 98%, 0% 0%, 33% 0%, 34% 8%, 37% 15%,  42% 17%, 50% 18%, 58% 16%, 64% 12%, 66% 8%, 67% 5%, 68% 2%, 69% 0%);    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="fondo" class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="div-notch ">
            sasas
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor mira esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197349/c%c3%b3mo-sustraer-quitar-relleno-a-una-figura-en-css3/197372#197372 Si quieres utilizar clip-path mira la respuesta de Alvaro Montoro. Para una solución alternativa mira mi respuesta (utiliza `box-shadow`)

Answer (score 0):

Para este ejemplo consideré 3 elementos:

- Un `div` que contendrá el círculo base o blanco que colocaremos parcialemente encima de la barra
- Dentro del `div` anterior coloco otro `div` para el círculo interno
- Un `div` externo que servirá para dibujar la barra

En cuanto a la maquetación:

- Al `div` que servirá como barra le coloco estilos genéricos solo para darle apariencia, tales como:

  - ancho definido
  - alto definido
  - color de fondo
  - bordes en las esquinas
- Al `div` que servirá como círculo contenedor del principal lo dibujo con:

  - La propiedad  [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
  - Le doy un color de fondo para que al momento de sobre ponerlo parcialmente sobre la barra genere el efecto de recorte
  - Lo muevo al darle un posicionamiento `relative` y desplazarlo con `top` y `left`
- Finalmente al círculo interno

  - Le doy un alto y ancho definido que sea mejor al del círculo blanco que lo contiene
  - Lo dibujo con `clip-path`
  - Le doy un posicionamiento relativo y lo desplazo con top y left

Código:

```html
    <style>
      #barra {
        background-color: teal;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      #circulo {
        background-color: white;
        clip-path: circle();
        height: 40px;
        left: 130px;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        width: 40px;
      }
      #final {
        background-color: crimson;
        clip-path: circle();
        height: 30px;
        left: 4.5px;
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        width: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="circulo">
      <div id="final"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="barra">
      
    </div>
```

Visualizandose así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesitaba que el borde que el notch que se generara fuera transparente,dando la sensación de que el circulo "corta" al otro elemento. He podido solucionarlo sin usar clip-path y con el comentario de @enxaneta.
Igualmente muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

He podido resolverlo con un truco bastante ingenioso que comento @enxaneta.

El truco básicamente consiste en crear un circulo transparente el cual sera nuestro notch, posterior a esto agregamos una sombra en la parte inferior dandole la forma y dimensiones deseadas.

```css
:root {
  --notch-size: 50px;
    --menu-width:  327px;
    --menu-height:  60px;
}

#menu-notch {
    margin:50px;
    /*sombra*/
  width: var(--menu-width);
  height: var(--menu-height);
  border-radius: calc(var(--menu-height)/2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-notch::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
    /*for notch*/
  background: transparent;
  width: var(--notch-size);
    height: var(--notch-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
    
  left: calc((var(--menu-width)/2) - ( var(--notch-size)/2  ) );
  top: calc(var(--notch-size)/-2);
  box-shadow: 0 calc(var(--notch-size) * 2) 0 var(--menu-width) blue;
}

body {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-notch">   
</div>
```